# Webform conditional component element invisible

Tags: webforms

While working with the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module (7.x-4.x), I found something I wasn't sure about.

I made a normal text field and then a selected list. After which I added conditional statements to make other things appear after the select list. One of which was another select list.

However, the label name for the second select list completely disappeared.

On closer inspection, ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> ) found the label had become invisible.

Any word of this? Is this a known bug?